# Do we use "early" or "late" to refer to the end of a decade in BCE?

Tags: history

So I'm writing an essay in which I want to refer to the years 483-480 BCE. Are these the late 480s or the early 480s? 83-80 are less than 89-84 in magnitude, but in BCE they are more recent than the latter period. So, is that period the late or early 480s?

Comment: The words *early* and *late* do not concern themselves with numerical indices.

Comment: @AntonSherwood can you clarify? No English speaker would deny that the phrases "late 20s" or "early 20s" has an obvious meaning. So, it would seem early and late do concern themselves with numerical indices?

Comment: "Early" definitely refers to a point in time before another time which is "late". But the fact that this is ambiguous to yourself might suggest that you should choose a different phrase entirely.

Comment: Probably a good idea. I'm just curious for knowledge's sake at this point if there is a convention though.

Comment: That is the convention; *early* is earlier than *late.* But as you note, it's slightly weird in this context.

Comment: Would you use *early/late* in speaking of, say, temperatures in the twenties?

Comment: @AntonSherwood - Are you saying that because it doesn't make sense to speak about temperatures that way that that somehow makes a difference to how we speak about years? Why would it? Using *early/late* when speaking about years is quite common and logical.

Comment: If your policy is that *early/late* is determined (in the context of years BCE) by the magnitude of the number, then I thought it ought to apply in other contexts where it does **not** do violence to temporal sequence.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know for sure, but I would say that later in time comes after earlier in time.

There 5 BCE is earlier in time than 1 BCE.  1 BCE is later in time than 5 BCE.

So I would say that 3-1 BCE is the later part of that decade (10-1 BCE).

I don't see how an instructor could mark me wrong if one time is later than another in chronology, not notation.

Comment: Yes; real-time reference (so later/latter always being closer to 2020 CE) trumps later applying metaphorically to an arbitrary labelling system.